# Cómo puedo traer una variable de una clase a otra?

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

Estoy intentando hacer una intefaz gráfica para una aplicación, a su vez estoy intentando usar la programación orientada a objetos para no replicar código. El problema que tengo es que quiero obtener una variable de una clase y ponerla en otra pero obtengo un error. Agradezco mucho si me pueden indicar cómo es el proceso correcto para poder llevar variables entre clases o si esto no es posible y poder replantear lo que estoy haciendo.

La variable que quiero pasar es self.GUI

Gracias

```
# El programa debe ser escrito en español
# El control de variables se hace de la siguiente manera
# Se dará a cada variable inmersa en un método las tres primeras letras del método más el número 1...n dependiendo de la cantidad de variables
# Ejemplo:  def unit(self): las variables asociadas a este método serían: uni1, uni2, uni3...unin
# A cada clase se le dará un nombre particular el cual estará dado de la siguiente manera CLS_A


# Librerías propias de PYTHON-------------------------------------------------------------------

import os

# Libreías auxiliares---------------------------------------------------------------------------

from Operate_System.OS_Resolution import* # Se encarga de extraer la resolución del dispositivo en uso
from Toolbar.Toolbar import* # Se encarga de generar la barra de herramientas flotante

# Librerías del módulo Tkinter------------------------------------------------------------------

from tkinter import*
from tkinter import filedialog, font, ttk, messagebox
from tkinter import LEFT, TOP, X, FLAT, RAISED
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Clase encargada de generar el GUI de la aplicación------------------------------------------------------------------

class ROOT():

    def __init__(self,img_carpeta,iconos):

        self.img_carpeta=img_carpeta
        self.iconos=iconos

        self.inix=screensize[0]
        self.iniy=screensize[1]

        
        self.GUI=Tk()

        self.ini1=iconos
        self.ini2=PhotoImage(file=self.ini1[0])

        self.GUI.geometry("{}x{}".format(self.inix,self.iniy))
        self.GUI.resizable(True,True)
        self.GUI.title("Paradigma 0.0.0")
        self.GUI.iconphoto(self.GUI,self.ini2)

# Instanciado de funciones provenientes de los módulos----------------------------------------------------------------

        #self.uni3=Toolbar()

class TOOLBAR(ROOT):

    def __init__(self,img_carpeta,iconos):
        TOO1=Frame(self.GUI)
        TOO1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
    

class FRAME(ROOT):
    pass








# Clase encargada de generar el GUI de la aplicación------------------------------------------------------------------

class APP(TOOLBAR,FRAME):
    pass


# Ejecuta la función que genera el GUI--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def f_verificar_iconos(iconos): #Descripción: Verifica la existencia de lás imagenes en la carpeta   
    
    for icono in iconos:
        if not os.path.exists(icono):
            print('Icono no encontrado:', icono)
            return(1)
    return(0)

def main():

    app_carpeta = os.getcwd()
    img_carpeta = (app_carpeta + os.sep + "images" + os.sep)
    
# Acá se introduce el vector de imágenes------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    iconos = (img_carpeta+"statistics.png",
        img_carpeta+"open_folder.png",
        img_carpeta+"New_file.png",
        img_carpeta+"Save.png",
        img_carpeta+"Save as.png",
        img_carpeta+"Tables.png",
        img_carpeta+"database.png")

    error1 = f_verificar_iconos(iconos)
       
    if not error1:
        app=APP(img_carpeta, iconos)
        app.GUI.mainloop()
    return(0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hola! Edité tu pregunta para que el código se vea mejor (lo puedes hacer tu mismo seleccionado el código y presionando las {} arriba de la caja de texto). También agregué las etiquetas Python y Tkinter. Recuerda agregar todas las etiquetas que consideres relevantes al hacer una pregunta, así esta llega a más gente y a la que sabe del tema. Al mismo tiempo, evitas hacer spam a las gente que tiene oculta dichas etiquetas.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu error que mencionas es aquí

```
class TOOLBAR(ROOT):

def __init__(self,img_carpeta,iconos):
    TOO1=Frame(self.GUI)
    TOO1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
```

¿Por qué pasa?

Si bien, tu clase `TOOLBAR` extiende de `ROOT`, al crear el `__init__` en `TOOLBAR` estás sobreescribiendo el `__init__` de `ROOT`

Explicado en un ejemplo más sencillo sería lo siguiente.

```
 class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init de Root')
        self.var_root = 'root'

class Toolbar(Root):
    def __init__(self):
        print('init de Toolbar')
        self.var_toolbar = 'toolbar'
```

Si ejecutamos

```
t = Toolbar()
```

El output sería

```
'init de toolbar'
```

Aquí podemos ver que a pesar de `Root` nunca entra a su `__init__` porque lo estamos redefiniendo.

Para poder llamar a su `__init__` de la clase padre (o cualquier función de la clase padre) podemos usar `super`.

```
class Root:
    def __init__(self):
        print('init de Root')
        self.var_root = 'root'

class Toolbar(Root):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('init de Toolbar')
        self.var_toolbar = 'toolbar'
```

Si ejecutamos

```
t = Toolbar()
```

El output sería

```
'init de root'
'init de toolbar'
```

Esto debido a que ahora sí estamos llamando al `__init__` del padre.

Volviendo a tu problema, solo basta con añadir la llamada del `__init__` al padre.

```
class TOOLBAR(ROOT):

def __init__(self,img_carpeta,iconos):
    # Aquí se llama el init de ROOT
    super().__init__(img_carpera, iconos)
    TOO1=Frame(self.GUI)
    TOO1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
```